# Stubbing Code for Test With Linq Expressions and Lambdas

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have query expression in my code that does the following:

```
repository.Context.AsQueryable<Option>().Where(o => o.Id == id && o.Name == "Something").Select(o => o.Id).ToArray();
```

How am I going to create a Stub for the above code? It seems like a lot of work. Is there anyway where I can simply ignore what is passed to the Where and Select methods and then return whatever I want to return?

I don't really care about what is passed in the Where and Select method. I just want to return my hard coded list of items in the end.

Comment: What's the type of `repository.Context`? Is it something you can mock on the repository?

Comment: Yeah I am already stubbing out repository and Context. I guess the question is that can I stub out Where. Can I say that I don't care what I pass in the Where method.

Answer (score 2):

As an option, use your code as a dependency. This way you can stub it without touching context at all. For example:

```
public class OptionService : IOptionService
{
    private IRepository _repository;

    public OptionService(IRepository repository)
    {
        _repository = repository;
    }

    public int[] GetOptionsWithName(int id, string name)
    {
        _repository.Context.AsQueryable<Option>()
                           .Where(o => o.Id == id && o.Name == name)
                           .Select(o => o.Id)
                           .ToArray();
    }
}

public interface IOptionService
{
    int[] GetOptionsWithName(int id, string name);
}
```

Inject `IOptionService` into your code with logic similar, how `IRepository` is injected into the `OptionService`, and stub the method `GetOptionsWithName` in the test to return whatever you want.

Comment: Definitely do this: it separates responsibilities, which is good. But when you want to test the behavior of `GetOptionsWithName()`, the same problem still arises. At some point you either have to have untested code, or come up with a way to test the LINQ statements.

Comment: Testing behavior (e.g. does the code call repository methods) is very arguable. Any code change may lead to rewriting the test. In contrast, testing the state doesn't contraint how exactly method gets the data. We just care about the result. Tomorrow we may decide to add caching, for instance, and the test will remain! That is great.

Comment: Behavior is exactly what you're supposed to be testing--it's the implementation details that the test shouldn't care about. Adding caching would probably change behavior enough that you'd want to change your unit tests to cover it or, arguably, implement the caching in a different class entirely. But I agree that you wouldn't want to test (e.g.) whether `.Where()` is called because there are multiple correct ways to realize the same behavior. I think if you test the method based on input and output data, then you're testing *behavior* rather than implementation details.

Comment: Testing the method based on input and output data, actually called "state-based testing" (see http://googletesting.blogspot.com/2013/03/testing-on-toilet-testing-state-vs.html). We don't know what happens inside and we don't care. We just need to get the expected result. Behavior or interaction-based testing - when you want to be sure that the method calls specific services, repository, etc. You know about its implementation and any change of it leads to changes in tests. From my experience, its much better to try to use only state-based tests.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is: No, because .Where() and .Select() are extension methods, which cannot be mocked.

The longer answer is: Yes, because `.Where()` and `.Select()` on `IQueryable<>`s do nothing but indicate to the underlying query provider that they were just called. So you could technically create a stub for the query provider and look at what happened to it before it got evaluated.

But the easy answer is: I've found the best approach is to use an actual in-memory representation that is capable of acting like a queryable, like a List. Then, rather than trying to validate the lambda expressions themselves, test the resulting data.

```
var options = new[] {new Option(...)};
repositoryMock.Setup(r => r.Context).Returns(contextMock.Object);
contextMock.Setup(c => c.AsQueryable<Option>()).Returns(options.AsQueryable());

...

Assert.AreEqual(results[0], options[0].Id);
```

The downside to this is that there's no way to test that your method only uses expressions that can be translated by your query provider. But I generally find this is "good enough" for unit-testing purposes.